# AMQ9660E: SSL key repository: password stash file absent or unusable

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq

On Linux using IBM MQ V9.2.0 I have seen the following error

```
EXPLANATION:
The SSL key repository cannot be used because MQ cannot obtain a password to access it. Reasons giving rise to this error include:
(a) the key database file and password stash file are not present in the location configured for the key repository,
(b) the key database file exists in the correct place but that no password stash file has been created for it,
(c) the files are present in the correct place but the userid under which MQ is running does not have permission to read them,
(d) one or both of the files are corrupt.
```

I did all the things mentioned in IBM docs but I am not able to resolve.

The SSLKEYR value is `/var/mqm/qmgrs/QMGRname/ssl/key`

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mqm mqm  80 Apr 21 14:31 key.rdb
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mqm mqm 193 Apr 21 14:32 key.sth
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mqm mqm 15K Apr 21 14:44 key.kdb
```

```
(mq:9.2.0.0)root@22955896bc26:/var/mqm/qmgrs/qmgr/ssl# runmqakm -cert -list -db /var/mqm/qmgrs/qmgr/ssl/key.kdb -stashed
Certificates found
* default, - personal, ! trusted, # secret key
!       "mns non-prod root ca"
!       "mns plc sub ca cate"
-       ibmwebspheremqqmgr
(mq:9.2.0.0)root@22955896bc26:/var/mqm/qmgrs/qmgr/ssl# runmqakm -cert -list -db /var/mqm/qmgrs/qmgr/ssl/key.kdb -stashed
CTGSK3026W The key file "/var/mqm/qmgrs/qmgr/ssl/key.kdb" does not exist or cannot be read.
CTGSK2101W The key database does not exist.
-Command usage-
-list                 Required <all | personal | ca>
-db | -crypto         Required
-tokenlabel           Required if -crypto present
-pw | -stashed        Optional
-type                 Optional <cms | kdb | pkcs12 | p12>
-secondarydb          Optional if -crypto present
-secondarydbpw        Optional if -secondarydb present
-secondarydbtype      Optional if -secondarydb present
-expiry               Optional
-rfc3339              Optional
-v                    Optional
```

```
$ runmqakm -cert -list -db /var/mqm/qmgrs/qmgr/ssl/key.kdb -stashed
Certificates found
* default, - personal, ! trusted, # secret key
!       "mns non-prod root ca"
!       "mns plc sub ca cate"
-       ibmwebspheremqqmgr
```

```
     1 : DIS QMGR SSLKEYR CERTLABL
AMQ8408I: Display Queue Manager details.
   QMNAME(qmgr)                        CERTLABL(ibmwebspheremqqmgr)
   SSLKEYR(/VAR/MQM/QMGRS/qmgr/SSL/KEY)
```

```
     1 : DIS QMGR SSLKEYR CERTLABL
AMQ8408I: Display Queue Manager details.
   QMNAME(qmgr)                        CERTLABL(ibmwebspheremqqmgr)
   SSLKEYR(/var/mqm/qmgrs/qmgr/ssl/key)
```

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mqm mqm 15088 Apr 28 17:18 /var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key.kdb
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mqm mqm    80 Apr 28 17:18 /var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key.rdb
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mqm mqm   193 Apr 28 17:19 /var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key.sth
```

```
(mq:9.2.0.0)root@22955896bc26:/var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl# su - mqm
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
$ getfacl /var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key.*
-su: 1: getfacl: not found
```

Comment: Have you tried to use runmqakm to access the kdb with the stashed option.  `runmqakm -cert -list -db key.kdb -stashed` should list the certs in the kdb.

Comment: Please tell us what platform you are having this problem on and show the directory listing and SSLKEYR value

Comment: @morag We are using Linux platform and SSLKEYR value is /var/mqm/qmgrs/QMGRname/ssl/key

Comment: @JoshMc I have used runmqckm -cert -list -db key.kdb -pw password command to list certs in kdb

Comment: The command you provided is not the command I suggested.   Using `-stashed` instead of `-pw` will **use** the `key.sth` file and help to prove it is valid.  Please also provide the specific version of IBM MQ that you are running.

Comment: @JoshMc we are using 9.2.0 version

Comment: @JoshMc after performing runmqakm -cert -list -db key.kdb -stashed command, following output is coming                 Certificates found
* default, - personal, ! trusted, # secret key
!       "mns non-prod root ca"
!       "mns plc sub ca cate"
-       ibmwebspheremqazmqgw

Comment: Can you show the ownership and access permissions of your key database file and stash file. Please edit your question to show this information.

Comment: @MoragHughson -rwxrwxr-x. 1 mqm mqm  80 Apr 21 14:31 key.rdb
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mqm mqm 193 Apr 21 14:32 key.sth
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mqm mqm 15K Apr 21 14:44 key.kdb,   Plz find the details

Comment: Hi, Can u guys help me fast. it is some urgent issue. Thank u

Comment: Run this command as the mqm user with the full path and make sure it works: `runmqakm -cert -list -db /var/mqm/qmgrs/QMGRname/ssl/key.kdb -stashed`. Please provide any output not in a comment but by clicking edit below your question and adding it. If it was a urgent issue I would expect you would open a case with IBM.

Comment: Given that your certificate label is `ibmwebspheremqazmqgw`, this suggests that your queue manager is called AZMQGW. This would mean that your `SSLKEYR` value should be `/var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW/ssl/key`. Please can you double check that it is correct.

Comment: @MoragHughson SSLKEYR value is same as you mentioned

Comment: @Murali - please can you UPDATE your question with these various extra bits of information. It is very hard to read the data in the comments when there are supposed to be new lines in the output.

Comment: @Murali please run this command and provide the output including the command itself: `runmqakm -cert -list -db /var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW/ssl/key.kdb -stashed`.  This command is slightly different that what I provided previously and is meant to validate the path contained in the `SSLKEYR`.  Please edit your question and add the output.

Comment: @Murali did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @JoshMc  No, it was not resolved

Comment: @JoshMc Updated answer . plz check it

Comment: It looks like your SSLKEYR doesn't match the directory the key.kdb is located in.

Comment: @JoshMc My SSLKEYR value is /VAR/MQM/QMGRS/AZMQGW02/SSL/KEY.  and i tried with runmqakm -cert -list -db /var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key.kdb -stashed with this command. U can see the output in my answer for this command

Comment: What is your `QMGR CERTLABL` set to?

Comment: CERTLABL(ibmwebspheremqazmqgw)

Comment: Can you please run this command as the mqm user,  in the prior output it looks like you ran it as root `runmqakm -cert -list -db /var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key.kdb -stashed`.  As root you could run `su - mqm` to become mqm.

Comment: @JoshMc posted the output. plzz check

Comment: Please provide the output of this command run as the mqm user: `echo "DIS QMGR SSLKEYR CERTLABL" | runmqsc AZMQGW02`

Comment: @JoshMc plz check the output, thanks

Comment: Please don't edit answers to provide comments, you can comment on the answer even with low points because it is an answer on your own question. You stated "I have changed to lower case and tried but same issue is facing."  Did you run the command I provided in my answer?  The REFRESH is key to this setting change taking effect.  You could also restart the queue manager and it will take effect.

Comment: @JoshMc i run refresh security type(ssl) and restarted channel but the same error is coming.

Comment: Can you again provide the output of `echo "DIS QMGR SSLKEYR CERTLABL" | runmqsc AZMQGW02` and of `/var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key.*`.

Comment: @JoshMc  Plzz check the output

Comment: Sorry also `ls -l /var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key.*`

Comment: @JoshMc )root@22955896bc26:/# ls -l /var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key
ls: cannot access '/var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key': No such file or directory

Comment: You missed the `.*` at the end of the command.  Please update the question with the result.

Comment: @JoshMc plz check the result

Comment: Please run `getfacl /var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key.*` and provide the output.

Comment: @JoshMc  plz find the output

Comment: I have no more ideas.  It is best practice to set the `key.*` to 600 (`chmod 600 /var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key.*`), but I  tested your permissions caused no problems. Take a trace, open a case with IBM and send them the trace. @MoragHughson, any other suggestions.

Comment: The question contains inconsistent information. Sometimes you are looking at `var/mqm/qmgrs/qmgr/ssl/key` and sometimes `var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key`. Can you actually do all the checks with one single directory. Someone reading this question in the future would just think you were using the wrong path, whereas I think you are perhaps editing the output? However, it is possible that you do have the wrong path somewhere. Why, for example does listing the exact same kdb cause a different result?

Comment: Also you have previously told us you `CERTLABL` is `ibmwebspheremqazgw02` and yet your kdb output shows a certificate called `ibmwebspheremqqmgr`. Is this also edited or is this actually what is in there? If you could edit your question to be real output we might be able tospot what was wrong. Not so likely with output as it currently stands.

Comment: @MoragHughson, If you look at the edit history that is what was done.  Originally the SSLKEYR was all upper case.  Correcting this didn't resolve.   I see nothing else wrong.

Comment: @JoshMc, Morag Hughson thanku u guys for ur help. one clarification, why i kept qmgr is it tells other people who will see this question will notices that it is qmgr name. Anyway thank u guys once again.

Comment: So is your problem resolved?

Comment: P.S. I think it would educate people more that it should be an actual queue manager name if you DON'T use `qmgr`. You would not believe how many first users create a queue manager called QMNAME because they don't realise they are supposed to replace that word in an example command with a queue manager name of their choosing! Saying at the start that your queue manager name is AZMQGW02 and then showing all the output with the queue manager name in place and not edited out would be much more educational for future readers in my opinion.

Comment: @MoragHughson problem was not resolved

Comment: If you are still looking for help, is it possible then that you could edit your question to show the CURRENT and REAL state of affairs on your system so we can see whether there is anything else wrong. It is very hard to tell when you know that the output is being edited and that you are not seeing real output. Also, you have two identical commands, one that works and one that fails. I don't understand the difference between those two commands. I assume at one point in time they were different, or it made sense, but now it doesn't.

Comment: Also, it might be worth noting that error message AMQ9660, that you are seeing - you should probably show the whole error btw, does say "If both are already present and readable in the correct place, delete and recreate them." as the final action.

Answer (score 0):

Unix is case sensitive, `/VAR/MQM/QMGRS/AZMQGW02/SSL/KEY` is not the same as `/var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key`.

To fix the issue run the following:

```
printf "ALTER QMGR SSLKEYR('/var/mqm/qmgrs/AZMQGW02/ssl/key')\nREFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL)\n" | runmqsc  AZMQGW02
```

Note that with MQSC commands if you do not surround a string with single quotes it will be folded to UPPER CASE.